# How to resize an SVG and all items inside it?

Tags: jquery, html, svg, polygon

I need to resize the svg and with it the polygon. If I try to change the height and the widht of the svg it just resize it and cut the polygon.
This is the code:

```
 <svg height="248" width="406" id="svg1" class="svg" style="position: absolute; top: 92px; left: 685px;">
    <polygon points="174,0 406,104 197,248 0,126 " style="fill: red; stroke: purple; stroke-width: 1;" id="poly1" class="polygon">
    </polygon>
    </svg>
```

I don't know if it makes any different, but I create both svg and polygon dynamically with JQuery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want for this is to set the `viewBox` property, in this case to `viewBox="0 0 406 248"`.

This defines the coordinate system of the virtual canvas, and when `height` and `width` are subsequently changed, it will scale instead of changing the size of the canvas.